PDoS using mBJ in vasp
I have calculated the band structure of a compound using mBJ-LDA potential and plotted it using the p4vasp package. However, i am not able to get Partial DoS from these calculations. I have followed the procedure mentioned here mBJ-LDA band structure calculation using VASP
to calculate the band structure. As i was not getting the information about PDoS using this method, i tried to calculate the same via the standard procedure:
Took WAVECAR and CHGCAR file from mBJ scf and then calculated the DoS using the following INCAR:
PREC = Accurate

 ENCUT = 500
 EDIFF = 1E-08

 IBRION = -1
 ISMEAR = -5
 ICHARG = 11

 LORBIT = 11


 NSW = 0
 NCORE = 4
 NEDOS = 1000




 SIGMA = 0.03
mBJ tags
METAGGA = MBJ
LASPH = .TRUE.

But the problem is after these calculations the system shows metallic behaviour despite having semiconducting nature as calculated using PBE GGA. What could be the reason for this error and what should be the correct way to calculate the PDOS using mBJ?
I kindly request for your help as it is very important for me. Thank you for your consideration.

You can refer to this question https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2061/1554, for PDOS make sure you have switched off the symmetry. Regarding the difference between DOS and BS, you can refer to this https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/9093/1554, make sure that you have a dense k-point grid.
